# MVC how to post a single value in the _layout file to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the _layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <input type="submit" name="pageSize" value="12" />
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Test co. ltd.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And as you see I added an input called pageSize, and what I need to do is when the user clicks the pageSize button, the "12" will be post to the controller, and I am thinking of posting the "12" through querystring `(i.e. when the user clicks the button, the url will be changed to www.myurl.com/propertyReport?pageSize=12)`

Currently, the button is displayed in the page, but there's no action when the button is clicked. How I can add an action to the button so the "12" will be passed to the controller?

Please note that I don't want to redirect to another page after clicking the button, I would like to post the 12 back to the controller and keep the existing url (i.e. something like this: `www.myurl.com/propertyReport?userID=123&from=20150201&pageSize=12`)

---

Update:

As per Stephen Muecke and Ivan's comment recommend, I added an Ajax.beginForm to wrap around the button:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Options", "Shared", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
    {
        <input type="submit" name="pageSize" value="12" />
    }
```

How the options method inside the shared controller is hit. So now I am able to get the "12" from query string, but now the problem is: what should I return in the ActionResult so I can stay on the same page?

SharedController:

```
public ActionResult Options(string pageSize)
{
    //Do stuff with the pageSize
    return //what should I return here?
}
```

Comment: You need a form to submit to a controller method, or you need to submit it using ajax if you want to say on the same page

Comment: If you don't want to change your url (and I suppose refresh page) then your only choice is ajax. You can call some controller method by ajax with needed values

Comment: @StephenMuecke you mean Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm()` is obsolete (its not even included in the latest MVC). You can just use the jQuery `.ajax()` functions (or one of the shortcuts such as `$.post()` or `$.get()`)

Comment: As for your edit, what do you want to return and what do you want to do with it? You can return a view (html) or json

Comment: I actually want to stay in the same page and keep the existing View, maybe jQuery.ajax is better is this situation

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed this into jquery post and the problem is solved:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to jquery post and now it solves the problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changePageSize(s) {
        $.post('/Shared/Options?pageSize=' + s, function (data, status) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Added this in the _Layout file and call this function whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: And why you need reload()?

Comment: Oh since I would like to refresh the page after posting to the controller

Comment: @User2012384, There is absolutely no point using `.reload()` if your posting data using ajax (it just pointless). If the method you calling is updating some data or you want to update part of the view, then the method should be returning a view (or json) and in the success callback, you update just that part of the existing page that is appropriate (by doing `reload()`, your not staying on the same page - your generating a new copy of it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, but my current situation is: I updated the size per page e.g. from 10 to 25, moreover, since this code is put in the _Layout file (Shared) so it's more difficult to update a part of the page, so I have to reload the page to generate the data that should be displayed for that page.

Comment: Oh then what should I use